# How can I burn an mkv file to DVD and change the default audio track?

Tags: dvd, burning, matroska

I have an mkv video file which has 3 audio tracks (English, Japanese and French). I'd like to burn it to DVD and still have all three audio tracks available, but I'd like to make the French audio the default (if possible).

**What program can I use to burn the mkv to DVD?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/)** will do that for you.

> DVD Flick aims to be a simple but at
>   the same time powerful DVD Authoring
>   tool. It can take a number of video
>   files stored on your computer and turn
>   them into a DVD that will play back on
>   your DVD player, Media Center or Home
>   Cinema Set. You can add additional
>   custom audio tracks, subtitles as well
>   as a menu for easier navigation.

Features

```
* Burn nearly any video file to DVD
* Support for over 45 file formats
* Support for over 60 video codecs
* Support for over 40 audio codecs
* Easily add a menu
* Add your own subtitles
* Easy to use interface
* Burn your project to disc after encoding
```

There's a [tutorial](http://beginwithsoftware.com/videoguides/dvd-flick-guide.html) on how to use it.

> I'd like to make the French audio the
>   default (if possible).

Simply move your preferred audio track to the top (highlight and click the 'Arrow Up' icon).

[image]

*DVD Flick is freeware.*

Answer (score 1):

DVD flick may have worked in the past , i don't know as i have only recently tried it , but i have thrown 20 different mkv files (made with "make MKV" ) at it, and it has failed to burn one single dvd . it always ends with an error

using win7 64bit  latest updates 2.8 GH 6g ram ...... it will NOT burn a DVD from MKV